# How to call a web api from url in mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created a web api with two parameters. I want to test it from url that its working or not. I have tried but not able to call. My code is.

API routing...

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {           
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }


[HttpGet]
    public List<Library> GetLibrary(string DataType, int DataId)
    {
        List<Library> LibraryList = new List<Library>();
        if (DataType == "Course")
        {
            using (ICA.LMS.Service.Models.Entities dbCourse = new Models.Entities())
            {
                LibraryList = (from c in dbCourse.COURSELIBRARies
                               where c.LIBITEMID == DataId
                               select new Library { Id = c.LIBITEMID, Name = c.GROUPNAME, Desc = c.DESCRIPTION }).ToList();
            }
        }
        return LibraryList;
    }
```

Url which i am putting in browser.

```
http://localhost:1900/api/librarybyid/?DataType='Course'&DataId=1
```

Result i am getting...

```
<Error>
   <Message>
       No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI     'http://localhost:1900/api/librarybyid/?DataType='Course'&DataId=1'.
   </Message>
   <MessageDetail>
      No type was found that matches the controller named 'librarybyid'.
    </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Comment: Please update the post with the controller name and api routing as it is in your code.

Comment: Do you name your controller as 'librarybyidController'? Because the error message clearly says "No type was found that matches the controller named 'librarybyid'"

Comment: Yes i have named it 'librarybyidController'. Then how would i call it from web browser?

Comment: Can you post the complete source of your controller. I tried a simple Web API service with a simple method (similar to the one in your example) and it is working fine.

Comment: Do you have any other methods in your Web API controller?

Comment: no i dont have any other method in that api .

Comment: Whether your controller base class is ApiController or not ?

Comment: thanks you all to for your response.